# is there a general formula for symmetric derivatives?

Tags: real-analysis

When a function $f: (a,b) \to R$ is differentiable at $x$, it is not hard to prove that

$$f'(x)=\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x-h)}{2h}.$$

Also, if $f$ is twice differentiable, then

$$f''(x)=\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h)+f(x-h)-2f(x)}{h^2},$$

which can be easily proved by using the Mean Value Theorem.

First of all, is there a third symmetric derivative?  Of course this means to write the third derivative of f at x (if exists) as a limit in terms of $f$ only (basically neither $f'$ nor $f''$).

How about a general formula for derivative of higher orders?

Thank in advance.

Comment: You can find a lot of these similar formulas in calculating numerical derivatives.

Comment: For a generalization to higher orders see 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference#Higher-order_differences and use the central difference formula

Comment: @gammatester That was what I was looking for.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Use the Taylor series:

$$f(x+2h)=f(x)+f'(x)(2h)+f''(x)(2h)^2/2!+f'''(x)(2h)^3/3!+...$$
$$f(x+h)=f(x)+f'(x)(h)+f''(x)(h)^2/2!+f'''(x)(h)^3/3!+...$$
$$f(x-h)=f(x)+f'(x)(-h)+f''(x)(-h)^2/2!+f'''(x)(-h)^3/3!+...$$
$$f(x-2h)=f(x)+f'(x)(-2h)+f''(x)(-2h)^2/2!+f'''(x)(-2h)^3/3!+...$$

Combine these equations to get $f'''(x)=F(f(x+2h),f(x+h),f(x-h),f(x-2h))$, by omitting higher order terms.

Comment: I don't see how to combine them in order to get rid of f' and f''.   I think @gammatester suggestions is the one that works perfectly.  Thank you